# Using prebuilt Opencv as thirdparty with Bazel: undefined symbol: gzopen

Tags: c++, opencv, bazel, undefined-symbol

I am trying to use OpenCV in my cpp project with bazel.

This is the structure:

```
-WORKSPACE
    -tutorial2
         main.cpp
         BUILD.bazel
         -thirdparty
              -opencv
                  -installdir
                       include
                       lib
```

I have this main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello Shell" << std::endl;
    cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3, CV_32FC1);
    std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the `BUILD.bazel` file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "opencv_lib",
    hdrs = glob(["thirdparty/opencv/installdir/include/opencv4/**/*h*"]),
    srcs = glob(["thirdparty/opencv/installdir/lib/**/*.a"])
)

cc_binary(
    name = "opencv_bin",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [":opencv_lib"],
    copts = [
        "-Itutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/include/opencv4",
        "-Ltutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/lib/",
        "-Ltutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/lib/opencv4/3rdparty",
        "-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib",
        "-lz",
        ],
)
```

But I get the linking error:

```
_arm64-fastbuild/bin/tutorial2/opencv_bin-2.params)
ld64.lld: error: undefined symbol: gzopen
>>> referenced by tutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o):(symbol cv::FileStorage::Impl::open(char const*, int, char const*)+0xd7c)

ld64.lld: error: undefined symbol: gzgets
>>> referenced by tutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o):(symbol cv::FileStorage::Impl::gets(unsigned long)+0x1ec)
>>> referenced by tutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o):(symbol cv::FileStorage::Impl::getsFromFile(char*, int)+0x48)
```

I have tried `rules_foreign_cc` but I don't think the caching is great and it is not working in Linux. Also I want to learn other ways of adding dependencies with bazel. What is the best strategy to add pre-built opencv to a c++ bazel project?

This is on my Mac.

Comment: that second include is a crime: `#include "tutorial2/thirdparty/opencv/installdir/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp"`

Comment: `gzopen` sounds like libgzip. opencv may depend on that. check for anything that should have been linked but isn't.

Comment: From what I can see it is zlib, which I am already linking to. Regarding the includes I am trying to understand bazel and getting something that works first.